# How The no Contact Voltage Detector circuit work?

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, bjt, voltage-detector

I saw the no Contact AC voltage detector circuit on some video on youtube and tried to make the circuit except that I wanted to replace it's led with an active buzzer with internal oscillator

- Problem is the sound is too dim and when I measured the voltage across the buzzer I found it to be less than 3 volts
  I used the same circuit in the picture except that I replaced the led and the resistor with my the buzzer which can safely operate with 9v and used an aluminum foil instead of this copper coil, *(" as I think it's working on capicitance after all " ) .*
- I want to know how can I increase the sound and How did I lost so much voltage without connecting any resistors.

[image]

Comment: Replace the LED with an opto-isolator and use its output to control a BJT or MOSFET switch to activate the buzzer, separately.

Comment: Or slide the switch and 1k resistor left, to where it reads "Positive (+)." Then whatever you connect in place of the LED will get full battery power. Note, the [BC547](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/BC546.pdf) has a maximum current rating of 100mA. As long as your buzzer consumes less than this, it should be ok.

Comment: @rdtsc actually I removed the Resistor and the LED completely from the circuit and and placed the active buzzer so The resistor is not what consuming this voltage

Comment: @jonk But why does the power decrease anyway? the buzzer is supposed to be in a parallel connection with the battery and it just got about 3v :(

Comment: @MahmoudSalah There's enough drive to support an LED but not enough for a buzzer. This is why you need something else added to the circuit.